# How to save data in database magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have integrated theme in magento2, and now I need to change In the registration form of theme.I need to add some field and save in database.
But I am new in magento2 and I didnt get the how to find controller for it and whats the flow?

So can any one have ideas about this?regarding how to start on customize in the theme?

Answer (score 1):

For add field, you can add field in Setup/UpgradeSchema.php in your custom module:

```
    namespace Name\moduleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface {


    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();


        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('tablename'), 'field name', [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'length' => 255,
            'comment' => 'xxxxx'
                ]
        );
   $installer->endSetup();
    }

}
```

but you should change setup_version in module.xml and setup:upgrade

Or just add in database direcly:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```